# xml to postgresql table by query

Tags: xml, postgresql

I need import data from xml to postgresql

Xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HouseStateStatuses>
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="0" NAME="descripton_1" />
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="1" NAME="descripton_2" />
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="2" NAME="descripton_3" />
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="3" NAME="descripton_4" />
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="4" NAME="descripton_5" />
</HouseStateStatuses>
```

I'd like to get the data into a postgresql table:

```
HOUSESTID |NAME
1         |descripton_1
2         |descripton_2
3         |descripton_3
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you go with upper case column names you'll probably regret it,

Comment: @Jasen it's what i have and can't changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with t(x) as (values('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HouseStateStatuses>
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="0" NAME="descripton_1" />
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="1" NAME="descripton_2" />
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="2" NAME="descripton_3" />
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="3" NAME="descripton_4" />
   <HouseStateStatus HOUSESTID="4" NAME="descripton_5" />
</HouseStateStatuses>'::xml))
select
  i::text::int as houseid,
  n::text as name
from 
  t,
  unnest(
    xpath('/HouseStateStatuses/HouseStateStatus/@HOUSESTID', x),
    xpath('/HouseStateStatuses/HouseStateStatus/@NAME', x)) as d(i,n);
```